# The rate of convergence of Markov chain to stationary distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, limits-and-convergence, markov-chains

Let $X_t$ is Markov chain with transition rates $c: G \times G \rightarrow [0: +\infty)$, where $c(x, y) > 0$, $c(x, x) = -\sum_y c(x, y)$ for $x \neq y$. If $\mu_t(x)$ is the distribution of chain at time $t$, then $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \mu_t(x) = \pi(x)$, but i want to know whether it depends on transition rates. Let $L$ is matrix of transition rates, $\mu_t = \mu_0 e^{tL}$ and our goal is calculation the limit: $\lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty} - 1/t \; log(sup \: |\mu_t^y(x) - \pi(x)|)$, where $\mu_t^y(x) = \mathbb{P}(X_t = x | X_0 = y)$. Let $L$ is diagonalizable.

My assumptions: Since $L$ is diagonalizable, then $L = SQS^{-1}$, where $Q = \begin{bmatrix}e^{\lambda_1 t}&...&0\\ ... & ... & ...\\0&...&e^{\lambda_n t}\end{bmatrix}$ and $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$ are eigenvalues. So, my question, how can i calculate $\lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty}log(sup|\sum_i v_{ij}e^{\lambda_it}u_{ji} - \pi(x)|)$ to understand, what rates $c$ is better to use. Could someone advice me books or articles to solve this problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_Chains_and_Mixing_Times